# Accessing android class through python code

Tags: android, python

I am working on a project where, I created an android app, when this app is running, a python script running in the background using sl4a, should be able to access a class of the app every few minutes by doing so a button is clicked on the app that performs a task automatically.

How can I make this possible?
can some one give me an idea or some links which could help me with it.
It is mandatory that I use only python for the triggering.